# Beaglebone Black Custom Audio Cape DMA/IRQ trouble

Tags: audio, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack, alsa

I'm running a BBB straight out of the box running debian. Kernel version is 3.8.13-bone-47.

I'm working with a cape that is very similar to the one [here](http://elinux.org/images/1/11/Audio_Cape_B1_Schematic.pdf). The difference is that I'm using a TLV320AIC3106 instead of the AIC3104, and I only have enabled the audio out, I'm not interested in recording audio in this application.

My pinout for my application is identical to the cape in the link above.

I've followed the link [here](http://elinux.org/BBB_Audio_Cape_RevB_Getting_Started) to get the cape up and running. Everything that I have matches the output of the tutorial up until I try and play a sample wave file.

When I play a sample wave file, I get the following message: `aplay: pcm_write:1710: write error: Input/output error`

Running `dmesg` gives me `ALSA sound/core/pcm_lib.c:1010 playback write error (DMA or IRQ trouble?)`

Where I'm having trouble is I don't understand how the DMA is coming in to play. Is this a DMA problem? Is it a symptom of something else going wrong like my I2C? Am I missing a configuration somewhere else?

Any thoughts on how to track this down are appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check whether the codec has been initialised by a driver or not.

Answer (score 0):

I realize it has been covered in multiple places before, but it can never be stressed enough. Make sure that when you're sending out information, make sure it goes to the right address over the I2C. I figured out this morning that the audio codec was at address 0x1B, while the driver was addressed to 0x18. Small but critical difference.

The easy fix is to edit the BB-BONE-AUDI-02-00A0.dts file.

- Edit line 65 to `<0x1B>`. Re-compile using the line: `dtc -O dtb -o BB-BONE-AUDI-02-00A0.dtbo -b 0 -@ BB-BONE-AUDI-02-00A0.dts`
- move the generated file to the /lib/firmware directory
- Insert it using `echo BB-BONE-AUDI-02 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr*/slots`

After applying this simple fix it seems to work. I can't say for certain because I have to get the audio amplifier circuit up and running still. At least aplay will play the file without crashing out on me, which is a start.

Comment: Hey, I am also getting the same problem for hikey. Is there anything that u can suggest me to look?